# How to give custom menu access to a role?

Tags: magento-1.9

I've seen other questions about this issue, the problem is that this is my config.xml my module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Envato_CustomConfig>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Envato_CustomConfig>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <customconfig>
                <class>Envato_CustomConfig_Helper</class>
            </customconfig>
        </helpers>
        <models>
             <customconfig>
                <class>Envato_CustomConfig_Model</class>
             </customconfig>
        </models>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <customconfig_options>
                                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                    <title>Custom Configuration Section</title>
                                </customconfig_options>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

And, this is my system.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <customconfig translate="label" module="customconfig">
            <label>Custom Configuration Tab</label>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
        </customconfig>
    </tabs>

    <sections>
        <customconfig_options translate="label" module="customconfig">
            <label>Custom Configuration Settings</label>
            <tab>customconfig</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <section_one translate="label">
                    <label>Section One</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                
                    <fields>
                        <custom_field_one>
                            <label>Custom Text Field</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment>Example of text field.</comment>                   
                        </custom_field_one>
                    </fields>
                </section_one>
                <section_two translate="label">
                    <label>Section Two</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                
                    <fields>
                        <custom_field_two>
                            <label>Custom Select Field</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>customconfig/options</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment>Example of select field.</comment>
                        </custom_field_two>
                        <custom_field_three>
                            <label>Custom Radio Field</label>
                            <frontend_type>radios</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>customconfig/options</source_model>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment>Example of radios field.</comment>
                        </custom_field_three>
                        <custom_field_four>
                            <label>Custom Multiselect Field</label>
                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>customconfig/options</source_model>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment>Example of multiselect field.</comment>
                        </custom_field_four>
                    </fields>
                </section_two>
            </groups>                
        </customconfig_options>
    </sections>
</config>
```

I have the acl, but in System >> Permisions >> role not found this module.

I need your help, ty ;)

Comment: you did not define your menu in config.xml

Comment: then, Why i dont have define my menu in config.xml but the menu is displayed?

Comment: I do this tutorial: http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration

Comment: Dont worry, solved

Comment: whts the update?how do you solve and update it as an answer?

Answer (score -1):

The problem I had was in the config.xml had not clearly defined the acl:

Before:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Envato_CustomConfig>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Envato_CustomConfig>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <customconfig>
                <class>Envato_CustomConfig_Helper</class>
            </customconfig>
        </helpers>
        <models>
             <customconfig>
                <class>Envato_CustomConfig_Model</class>
             </customconfig>
        </models>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <customconfig_options>
                                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                    <title>Custom Configuration Section</title>
                                </customconfig_options>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

After:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Envato_CustomConfig>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Envato_CustomConfig>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <customconfig>
                <class>Envato_CustomConfig_Helper</class>
            </customconfig>
        </helpers>
        <models>
             <customconfig>
                <class>Envato_CustomConfig_Model</class>
             </customconfig>
        </models>
    </global>
   <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <customconfig_options>
                                            <title>HOLA MUNDO</title>
                                        </customconfig_options>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Comment: ACLs and menus should go in `adminhtml.xml`. Putting them in `config.xml` has been deprecated since 1.6.